# Can Begotten do hedgespinning and oneiromancy?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, changeling-the-lost

One player in our CtL campaign generated a Beast from Beast: the Primordial. As soon as we started going into Hedge and breaking into other people's dreams, it turned out they don't know what to do and whether they can do anything. The book just says that any Fae creature can do that (but not fae-touched), but it's unclear if Begotten qualify. So, can they perform hedgespinning?

(Clarification: I don't mean Beast seeming, I mean Begotten from B:tP. [Makara](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Makara_(BTP)), to be precisely)